# Does DNSCrypt mask/hide the URLs I visit

Tags: http, dns

I use `DNSCrypt` (https://dnscrypt.org/) and I'd like to know whether it's useful to mask/hide from my `ISP` (`Telecom`) the `HTTP` requests I make in my browser.
And how does it protect me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... whether it's useful to mask/hide from my ISP (Telecom) the HTTP requests I make in my browser.

From the [homepage of dnscrypt](https://dnscrypt.org/):

> Please note that DNSCrypt is not a replacement for a VPN, as it only authenticates DNS traffic, and doesn't prevent "DNS leaks", or third-party DNS resolvers from logging your activity.)

Thus the answer to your question is: NO, it does not hide the DNS requests from your ISP. DNSCrypt is not a privacy tool but only prevents spoofing of DNS responses.